# v4l2loopback cannot load module on aws ubuntu 18.04

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-18.04, v4l2, v4l2loopback

Currently trying to install v4l2loopback into a ubuntu 18.04 instance at aws and facing the current situation

After running (the same happens from source install)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic (tempts to load videodev)
sudo apt-get install v4l2loopback-dkms
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
```

I have the following error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'v4l2loopback': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg
```

The same happens for loading `videodev` (`sudo modprobe videodev`)

Is there any way to recompile the kernel loading the `v4l2`/`videodev` modules? Or any alternative for v4l2loopback on cloud instances?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error in my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and fix by disabling secure boot which lock modules loading into kernel.

```
sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```

Use this command which require new password, then reboot the system.
In the boot stage, a blue window appear where you need to choose the "change secure boot stage" section, after password validation and booting to system `modprobe` function should work.

If `mokutil`does not exist in your system you can install them from `apt-get`.